# Django 1.7 migration to add raw query to set auto_increment initial value

Tags: django

I am using Django v1.7 and I need to set the initial auto increment value to something like 1000000, I couldn't find any Django docs that shows there is a feature like this, and the model I have have a lot of dependencies, so it's not easy to create a dummy record with key specified and then delete it.

So the only sensible way I think is to put `alter table tablename auto_increment=1000000` in the initial migration file, but I also cannot find a way in this [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/)

The question is how do I do that in the new migration system?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sweet, found this [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/migration-operations/#runsql)

Just add this in the operations array

```
operations = [
    migrations.CreateModel(...),
    # mysql specific
    migrations.RunSQL('alter table tablename auto_increment=1000000'),
]
```